# Leer un objeto de JSON desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

he encontrado muchos foros y textos en donde lo explican a detalle, el problema es que nada me funciona y lo he intentado de muchas maneras.
Les dejo el JSON y cómo trato de leerlo sin tener resultados diferente de:

> application.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (application.js:29)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)

Gracias de antemano por su respuesta.

```
    [ { 0: "14460243",
         1: "", 
         2: "RICARDO RAFAEL ", 
         3: "VILLAGRANA LARIOS",  
         4: "VILLAGRANA", 
         5: "LARIOS", 
     ncont: "14460243", 
  mtricula: "", 
    nombre: "RICARDO RAFAEL ", 
  apellido: "VILLAGRANA LARIOS", 
        AP: "VILLAGRANA", 
        AM: "LARIOS" } ]
```

y este es mi codigo con el que pretendo leer:

```
$('#load-more').click(function(){
    $.get('api/fields.php?code=show',function(data){
            var content = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(content)
        })
        alert(content[0].nombre)
});
```

Esto se ejecuta cuando acciono un botón

```
<button id="load-more" style="margin: 150px;" class="btn btn-color-2"> <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Cargar más </button>
```

Comment: no pongas en imagen porfavor

Comment: Puedes añadir el código html dónde se ejecuta esto?

Comment: El objeto es válido, por lo que debería leerse con un simple `forEach`. Provee más detalles, ¿alcanzas a realizar el parsing a json? ¿qué muestra `console.log(content)`?

Comment: Lo que publicaste no es un JSON válido

Comment: @guzgarcia sí me regresa el objeto como debe ser, puedo explorar los datos bien

Comment: El JSON si es valido lo acabo de testear

Comment: @CarlosLucero entonces claramente no es lo que publicó... JSON no es un objeto, sino la representación como string del mismo... Podés evaluarlo en cualquier validador online

Comment: @Mariano tienes razón lo probé como un objeto literal, los key deben ser cadenas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la llamada Ajax es asíncrona, cuando realizas la petición Ajax javascript continua a la siguiente linea de ejecución donde muestras el 'alert', la respuesta llegara posteriormente luego de que el 'alert' ya fue mostrado, teoricamente la respuesta puede llegar antes de que el 'alert' sea invocado y te muestre la información pero la latencia de una llamada Ajax es enorme comparado con la ejecución del script ya que la primera esta sujeta a la latencia de red mientras que la segunda esta sujeta a los ciclos del procesador.

la linea console.log(content) debe mostrarte el resultado pero no el 'alert'.

Para controlar el flujo de ejecución y sea serial puedes usar promises, sin embargo todo es serial dentro del contexto de los promises, cualquier código fuera del promise no seguira el mismo flujo de ejecución serial.

```
$.get('api/fields.php?code=show')
  .done(function( data ) {
     var content = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(content)
     alert(content[0].nombre)
  });
```

Comment: Gracias por esa explicación, la pasé por alto, me funcionó muy bien.

Comment: Para aclarar las dudas el JSON que nos muestras esta mal formado como lo indica @Mariano, ademas como lo indico también German, la variable content esta declarada en la función callback por lo que no tienes acceso a dicha variable fuera de la función, de cualquier forma si declarabas la variable fuera de la función dejando el alert donde lo tienes (fuera del callback) el problema es el que ya mencioné

Answer (score 1):

El error exacto te está dando, porque fuera de la función de `$.get` de jQuery no has definido `content`, y estas haciendo un alert, lo mejor seria hacerlo dentro, de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#load-more').click(function(){
    $.get('api/fields.php?code=show', function(data) {
        var content = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(content);
        alert(content[0].nombre)
    })
});
```

Tambien seria bueno que verificaras primero si data es un string, para luego pasarlo por `JSON.parse`

Comment: ¿De qué hablas? Veo claramente que define `content` dentro del callback y le asigna el objeto parseado.

Comment: si no te das cuenta, content está definida dentro de una funcion asincrona, y al hacer el llamado, no existe fuera de esa función @guzgarcia

Comment: Vale, sí, es correcto. Leí mal el código del OP en el móvil.

Answer (score 0):

Ami esto me funciona logro traer la data hasta la consola del navegador ahora quiero es leer esos datos para mostrarlos en un tabla.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var url="http://localhost/TDA_Francisco_Astudillo/modelo/vista/home.html";

        console.log("Esta es la url "+window.location);
        if (url == window.location) {
            $.get(  "../../modelo/controlador/ctrl_home.php"
                ,{
                    action:"data"
                },function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });

            //console.log("Si entra ");
        }
});
```

En el código php mando:

```
while ($traducir=$result->fetch_array()) {
            echo json_encode($traducir);
        }
```