# Recoger datos de JSON con [ ] desde Javascipt

Tags: javascript, json

quiero plantear un problema que tengo y no veo solución aparente en internet. Tengo un archio .json con este formato:

```
[{"id":"hola"}, {"id":"adios"}]
```

Cuando quiero recoger estos datos en JS como lo hago

```
var id= JSON.parse(AQUI QUE PONGO);
```

Se que si en el archivo json le coloco un nombre al array y luego aplico JSON.parse me funciona. Pero no lo quiero hacer de este modo.
Gracias y saludos

Comment: explica mejor lo que deseas obtener

Comment: @jose si quieres recorrer un array desde un archivo externo en un archivo js debes hacer una petición para poder traer estos datos...

Comment: He simplificado el caso. Con el formato que he descrito para el archivo json. Como mostrarias, en JS, un alert con la palabra adios.

Comment: @jose esto te serviría? var data  =[{"id":"hola"}, {"id":"adios"}]
  alert(data[1]["id"])

Comment: Aquí hay un montón de preguntas relacionadas las has visto? [Leer un objeto de JSON desde Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/41751/69447), [¿Como puedo extraer los datos en este JSON mediante javascript y html?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/62636/69447) ....

Comment: El primer enlace, en la respuesta se utiliza jquery. En el segundo enlace, en la respuesta ya predefine un objeto dentro del mismo archivo. No me vale esto

Answer (score 1):

es facil, tu estructura esta basada en un array[objecto], simplemente lo puedes recorrer con each de jQuery y posteriormente leer sus indices en su interior:

link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

ejemplo practico:

```
$.each(JSON.parse('[{"id":"hola"}, {"id":"adios"}]'), function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value.id );
});
```

ejecutalo en consola, una vez que haya cargado la api de jQuery.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería una buena forma:

```js
let myvar = [{"id":"hola"}, {"id":"adios"}];

for(i in myvar){
 let current = myvar[i].id;
 console.log(current);
}
```

Y así puedes hacer con objetos que contengan más propiedades, por ejemplo:

```
[{"id":"hola", "nombre": "juan", "numero": 1}, {"id":"hola", "nombre": "pedro", "numero": 2}];
```

```js
let myvar = [{"id":"hola", "nombre": "juan", "numero": 1}, {"id":"hola", "nombre": "pedro", "numero": 2}];

for(i in myvar){
 let current = myvar[i];
 console.log(current.nombre);
 console.log(current.numero);
 //etc ...
}
```

Esto es así porque lo que tienes es un Array de objetos, por ejemplo:

```
          let o1 = {'id':"hola", 
                    'nombre': "juan", 
                    'numero': 1};
```

que pueden ir añadiendose al Array así:

```
let myArray = [];
myArray.push(o1);
```

y ejecutar las operaciones que he descrito más arriba.

Comment: Mas que un simple bloque de código siempre es bueno acompañarlo de una explicación de lo que haces en el método, de modo que esto no simplemente cubra la necesidad de este usuario, sino de cualquier otro usuario que tenga una duda semejante. :)

Comment: Gracias @J.Rodríguez, He añadido algunas explicaciones

Answer (score 0):

Analizando un poco tu pregunta llegue a esta conclusión, quieres mostrar un Dato en un archivo `JS` de un archivo `.JSON` para esto yo haría lo siguiente:

1- Petición `HTTP` para traer los datos que necesito:

script.js

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var res = this.responseText;
            var converRes= JSON.parse(res);
            alert(converRes[1].id);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "data.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

data.json

```
[{
    "id":"hola"
}, {
    "id":"adios"
}]
```

Como puedes ver en la función `javascript` realizo una petición donde tengo una variable llamada `res` donde almaceno el `objeto` en formato texto, seguidamente tengo una variable llamada `converRes` donde convierto la cadena de texto en el `objeto` que necesito y luego hago el `alert` con el `id` que quiero, en este caso `"id":"adios"`
Espero que te sirva esta respuesta y si es lo que necesitas, quedo pendiente ante cualquier pregunta...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No había contemplado esta posibilidad. He estado leyendo algo sobre la petición HTTP y parece que se utiliza para leer Json de estructura desconocida. He probado el código pero no me va. Debe ser que estoy haciendo algo mal. De todas maneras usaré la definición de objeto dentro del archivo json y aplicare JSON.parse directamente. El real problema que tengo con definir el objeto es cuando intento actualizar un valor mediante php. Que no lo identifica como un array. Pero eso sería ya otro tema. Gracias por todo

Comment: @jose ok de todas maneras fue mi respuesta a tu pregunta, a la próxima has una pregunta mas especifica para poder determinar que hacer, saludos.